# apache camel : generate random numeric ID in xslt

Tags: apache-camel, xslt-2.0, numeric

In apache camel, I am using xslt to create xml request. I want to generate random ID and pass it as RequestID as one of attribute. Is there any way to generate numeric ID in xslt.

```
<RequestID>12345</RequestID>
```

There are few conditions like number should contain only numeric value and no alphabets.
It should be maximum 8 digit.

Comment: It is not clear in what kind that random number on the one hand has to serve as an ID, numeric IDs could be generated with `xsl:number`. As `random-number-generator` is part of XPath 3 and XSLT 3 and not XPath or XSLT 2, for random number generation you would probably first look into processor specific extensions. Or FXSL.

Comment: Do you need to produce just one single "random" Id in the result of the transformation, or many (how many?) such numbers?

Answer (score 0):

FXSL (https://github.com/dnovatchev/FXSL-XSLT2) has pure XSLT 2 support for random numbers, I am struggling to find the right way to ensure the 8 digits but at least

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:import href="https://github.com/dnovatchev/FXSL-XSLT2/raw/master/Tests/test-random.xsl"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="random-number" as="xs:double">
      <xsl:call-template name="randomSequence">
        <xsl:with-param name="pLength" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pSeed" select="(current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="100"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <RequestID>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number($random-number, '00000001')"/>
    </RequestID>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives a random number on each invocation. I am sure Dimitre will come along later to post a more informed answer on how to use his library for your case.

Comment: Actually import is not recommended. I was checking if I can convert time from date as random number and use it